# Getting Permissions for Facebook Pages

Tags: facebook, permissions

I'm frantically trying to migrate my app to the new authentication model, it broke the other day when Facebook removed the fb_sig stuff.

Does anyone know how to request the publish_stream permission for a fan page?  I can't find any good examples out there using the new Graph API stuff.  I already have the code to store the access token, I just need to find a way to request this permission somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're asking for or not, but to get the proper permissions, I first check to see if there's a user, then check to make sure that I can get to the permissions that I need.  If I can't, then I forward to the loginURL from FB and ask for the proper permissions:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if($user) {
    try {
      $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
      $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('canvas' => 0, 'scope'=>'offline_access,publish_stream,email'));
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$url';</script>";
      error_log($e->getType());
      error_log($e->getMessage());
    }   
} else {
    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('canvas' => 0, 'scope'=>'offline_access,publish_stream,email'));
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$url';</script>";
}
```

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: You can also use the more up to date LoginURL code - 
$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'offline_access,publish_stream,email','redirect_uri'=>'https://apps.facebook.com/myApp/'));

Comment: I think that is for the user though, I'm looking for the permission on his pages.

Comment: I think I understand what you're looking for.  You want specific permissions that the user has for a specific page?  Can you use something like:

$graph_url="https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?".$access_token;

$user_permissions = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));

Then use the $user_permissions object to see what they have access to?

Comment: Actually, I want to post to a page as the page.  To do so, you need to get the publish_stream permission for that page itself - I can't figure out how to do this with the new oauth2.  I used to use this: <a href="#" onclick="Facebook.showPermissionDialog('publish_stream', relaunchPage, true)

Comment: Ok, you just went past what I've done.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help.  Good luck on that!  Please post the solution when you find it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I needed to do.  I got the access_token for the page itself.  After that, I just used this function: http://www.yorkstreetlabs.com/blog/Publish-to-Your-Facebook-Pages-Wall-with-PHP